# Jenkins HTML Publisher - Provide dynamic folder name to Path in HTML Publisher Plugin

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, continuous-integration, extent

I am generating an extent report every time my regression suite runs. The project folder structure is ProjectFolder/Results. I am running the regression suite from Jenkins job. So whenever the regression suite is executed, a folder is created under the Results folder with the name Regression_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. The YYYYMMDDHHMMSS is the current time-stamp. Then the extent report is saved here. I want to set HTML Publisher as Post Build action. In this how do I set the path of the folder (Results/Regression_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS) as the path is dynamic

Please suggest the steps.

Comment: Any idea around this? any suggestions pls.

Answer (score 1):

Well one can extract file name at run time and rename/copy it to some unique value
and then publish the report
E.g

```
//Get the folder name of the report and remove the newline while is appened by sh
REPORT_NAME = sh (label: 'GetLatestResultFileName', returnStdout: true, script: 'ls -t results | head -n1').trim()

Validating if we have extracted right folder name
sh "echo $REPORT_NAME"
sh "ls results/$REPORT_NAME"

//Choose a unique name for folder. for me HTMLReport was. unique in my result folder and was not gono be used by my gatling test 
sh "cp -rf results/$REPORT_NAME results/HTMLReport"

//Finally publish this report using HTML publisher
publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, includes: '**/*.html', keepAll: true, reportDir: 'results/HTMLReport', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'GatlingLatestReport', reportTitles: ''])

//Cleanup
sh "rm  -rf results/HTMLReport"
```

Comment: Good idea , thanks.